# I want to validate that user can only select only one checkbox in each row in listview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have listview with two checkboxes in itemtemplate.
I want to validate that user can only select only one checkbox in each row.

Comment: Are you willing to use any javascript libraries?

Comment: Why aren't you using radio groups?

Comment: This answer fixes the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group/9709425#9709425

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're describing is accomplished using standard HTML radiobuttons. If you change your design to use these you'll get the benefit that

1. The user can only select a single item, no extra javascript needed
2. Users expect to be able to choose multiple checkboxes but only a single radiobutton IE you're working with their expectations

If you're still sure you want to use jQuery then something like this should do it.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).siblings(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: cannot use radiobuttons as I am doing something like user can select All option for either of the two check boxes or he can select individual checkbox but he cannot select both the options at a time.Its purpose is it send either mail or sms to end users from list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. had also asked one of my friend and he gave me the following solution which is working fine. Posting it, if anybody needs it.-

say ur checkboxes in the 2 clumns are named EmailCheckBox and SMSCheckBox

then use this code to toggle the checkboxes in each single row:

```
$('input:checkbox[id*=EmailCheckBox]').click(uncheckOthercheckbox);
$('input:checkbox[id*=SMSCheckBox]').click(uncheckOthercheckbox);


        function uncheckOthercheckbox() {

            if (this.id.indexOf("EmailCheckBox") != -1) {

                var otherCheckBoxId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("EmailCheckBox")) + "SMSCheckBox";
            }
            else {

                var otherCheckBoxId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("SMSCheckBox")) + "EmailCheckBox";
            }

            var i = "#" + otherCheckBoxId;
            if (this.checked) {

                $(i).removeAttr('checked');
            }                

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@vinit,
just a little change, you forgot the else part,

```
$('input:checkbox[id*=EmailCheckBox]').click(uncheckOthercheckbox);
$('input:checkbox[id*=SMSCheckBox]').click(uncheckOthercheckbox);

        function uncheckOthercheckbox() {

            if (this.id.indexOf("EmailCheckBox") != -1) {

                var otherCheckBoxId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("EmailCheckBox")) + "SMSCheckBox";
            }
            else {

                var otherCheckBoxId = this.id.substring(0, this.id.indexOf("SMSCheckBox")) + "EmailCheckBox";
            }

            var i = "#" + otherCheckBoxId;
            if (this.checked) {

                $(i).removeAttr('checked');
            }
            else {

                if ($(i).attr('checked') === false) {
                    $(i).attr('checked', 'checked');
                }
            }

        }
```