# html select only one checkbox in a group

Tags: html, checkbox

So how can I only allow a user to select only one checkbox?

I know radio buttons are "ideal", but for my purpose...it's not.

I have a field where users need to select either or of the two options, but not both. The problem is that I need my users to also be able to unselect their option, and this is where radio buttons fail because once you select the group, you have to choose an option.

I will be validating the info via php, but I'd still like to restrict the users to one answer if they want to give it.

Comment: With HTML only, this can't be done.  You'll need JavaScript.  If you're open to jQuery, I can give you a quick solution.

Comment: What about an extra radio button labelled "none"?

Comment: a 3rd option doesn't go well with my design...good alternative though :)

Comment: Checkbox with a single choice is actually a radio-button. Won't this surprise users?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams It could be done in HTML, see my answer. In most cases though, that JS is simpler and there is no need for hacks.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

This snippet will:

- Allow grouping like Radio buttons
- Act like Radio
- Allow unselecting all

```js
// the selector will match all input controls of type :checkbox
// and attach a click event handler 
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <h3>Fruits</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Kiwi</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Jackfruit</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Animals</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Tiger</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Sloth</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />Cheetah</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The correct usage would be to use $(this).is(":checked") the "is" to check if the checkbox was being checked in the if { ... } else { ... } here ... http://jsfiddle.net/zGEaa/31/

Comment: Note that .attr is no longer working, use .prop("checked") instead for newer versions of jQuery

Comment: You missed the radio selector: $("input:checkbox.radio")

Comment: @Sven - It would be an overly specific selector in this example. Having said that if the page contains another set of checkboxes that should not have this behaviour, then using the `.radio` selector would help. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);---:Beautiful code.

Comment: not worked when check box are in grid having paging @bPratik

Comment: @nikhiljain - of course this code snippet won't work across all pages in a paged grid. This snippet relies on all the elements being in the DOM. Whereas in a paged grid (most likely using a JS component) the complete list of rows and their selection state will be held in a JS object that mimics the whole grid. You'll need to directly modify that object if you want the functionality across pages.

Comment: instead of var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";  i used  var group = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

Comment: The problem with that @RickWeb is you are targeting absolutely all checkboxes on the page, and making them act as a single group. The `name` attribute of a checkbox element is what groups it in a form.

Comment: How should I know to use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`? That's confunsing.

Comment: @maciejwww - Sorry I don't understand. Are you asking how to use the `<script>` tag that adds the `jquery` library? That line should be included in the `<head>` section of the webpage.

Comment: I mean where I should look for the source. How can I know it (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`) will help me? Using this source is a confusing problem solution - how can I know how it works, how will work?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389971/select-only-one-checkbox-in-group/29390007#29390007) solution appeals to me more and seems to be more proper programming way.

Comment: I mean there is no way I will get an idea of using exactly this source (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`) without looking for a solution on the web.

Comment: @maciejwww I agree with you partially. The answer could definitely be a bit more explanatory. On the other hand, the jQuery library that you are referring to was added for completeness. For example, the answer that you have linked also uses jQuery, but does not mention including it anywhere. Thus would take the same amount of Google-fu to find out what `$(something)` does. I'll update my answer later to be a bit better. But feel free to edit it yourself too!

Comment: Nah, I don't question your answer. I'm just curious where I should look for to get and use something like this source. Where is it, where is it explained, and how to get familiar with it (simply, quick way of using it)?

Answer (score 139):

You'd want to bind a `change()` handler so that the event will fire when the state of a checkbox changes. Then, just deselect all checkboxes apart from the one which triggered the handler:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X597P/)

---

As for grouping, if your checkbox "groups" were all siblings:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>  
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>   
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

You could do this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
   $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X597P/9/)

---

If your checkboxes are grouped by another attribute, such as `name`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" />

<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" />

<input type="checkbox" name="group3[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group3[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="group3[]" />
```

You could do this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EB2qC/1/)

Comment: I like your (last) code. Very short and still clear. I wasn't sure if the on 'change' would fire up as you change the other checkboxes, but it didn't when I tried it. So I prefer your code. Thanks! :)

Comment: I really like this, I've got to do a slight tweak for my need. I have two items so the first item is checked by default and if its unchecked the second item  becomes checked. This helped me get started.

Comment: Hi @john.weland - do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/d7sd04by/)?

Comment: @billyonecan almost exactly but with the ability to target a given grouping. [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/johnweland/d7sd04by/2/). Thanks

Comment: plus one for simplicity

Comment: Great, this was helpful! I had to implement this for only some checkboxes on the page which I wanted to behave like radio buttons. So I used multiple selectors this:
`$('input[type="checkbox"][id*="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});` 
The checkboxes which I wanted to behave like radio buttons had '_radio' added in the id.

Answer (score 48):

There are already a few answers to this based on pure JS but none of them are quite as concise as I would like them to be.

Here is my solution based on using name tags (as with radio buttons) and a few lines of javascript.

```js
function onlyOne(checkbox) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check')
    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {
        if (item !== checkbox) item.checked = false
    })
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="onlyOne(this)">
```

Comment: Thank you, this one did it for me from all those others =)

Answer (score 28):

Radio buttons are ideal. You just need a third "neither" option that is select by default.

Comment: That's a good solution, but I rather stick with checkboxes because my design isn't ideal for a 3rd option.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest changing the design. *Tick 0 or 1 of these 2 options* is not a common pattern and won't be as intuitive to users as *Tick 1 of these 3 options*

Comment: why would I change my whole design for 2 checkboxes?

Comment: If such a change would require you to change "your whole design" then that suggests that design is far too inflexible in the first place.

Comment: It's not inflexible, it just doesn't look right...It may look fine on forms and such applications, but we have different usage for our checkboxes.

Comment: Old answer but on top of that radio buttons can be tricky to handle from an accessibility point of view. When using the keyboard, you can't go through the different options without selecting the last focused one. Which is super annoying and makes things impossible to handle when you need to show other elements on selection. Most of the time you'll need to rely on buttons or checkboxes even if radios are "ideal" and semantic freaks friendly. Design is not just visual.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("#myform input:checkbox").change(function() {
    $("#myform input:checkbox").attr("checked", false);
    $(this).attr("checked", true);
});
```

This should work for any number of checkboxes in the form.  If you have others that aren't part of the group, set up the selectors the applicable inputs.

Comment: yes sir :) It's ok, I found something that works for me, though your solution looks pretty simple. I probably did something wrong on my end. Thanks anyways.

Comment: $("#myform input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);

Answer (score 6):

May this code helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slectOne').on('change', function() {
   $('.slectOne').not(this).prop('checked', false);
   $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $('#result').html($(this).data( "id" ));
   else
    $('#result').html('Empty...!');
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="1 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="2 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="3 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="4 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="5 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="6 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="7 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="8 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="9 selected"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="slectOne" data-id="10 selected"/>
<span id="result"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Working link [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB6JK5HW3Z53)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple HTML and JavaScript solution I prefer:

//js function to allow only checking of one weekday checkbox at a time:

```
function checkOnlyOne(b){

var x = document.getElementsByClassName('daychecks');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if(x[i].value != b) x[i].checked = false;
}
}


Day of the week:
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Monday" />Mon&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Tuesday" />Tue&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Wednesday" />Wed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Thursday" />Thu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Friday" />Fri&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Saturday" />Sat&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="daychecks" onclick="checkOnlyOne(this.value);" type="checkbox" name="reoccur_weekday" value="Sunday" />Sun&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 5):

My version: use data attributes and Vanilla JavaScript

```
<div class="test-checkbox">
    Group One: <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupOne" value="Eat" />Eat</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupOne" value="Sleep" />Sleep</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupOne" value="Play" />Play</label>
    <br />
    Group Two: <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupTwo" value="Fat" />Fat</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupTwo" value="Comfort" />Comfort</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-limit="only-one-in-a-group" name="groupTwo" value="Happy" />Happy</label>
</div>
<script>
    let cbxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][data-limit="only-one-in-a-group"]');
    [...cbxes].forEach((cbx) => {
        cbx.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
            if (e.target.checked)
                uncheckOthers(e.target);
        });
    });
    function uncheckOthers (clicked) {
        let name = clicked.getAttribute('name');
        // find others in same group, uncheck them
        [...cbxes].forEach((other) => {
            if (other != clicked && other.getAttribute('name') == name)
                other.checked = false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Building up on [billyonecan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087721/billyonecan)'s answer, you can use the following code if you need that snippet for more than one checkbox (assuming they have different names).

```
    $('input.one').on('change', function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        $('input[name='+name+'].one').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Checkbox Group

```js
var group_=(el,callback)=>{
el.forEach((checkbox)=>{
callback(checkbox)
     })
}

group_(document.getElementsByName('check'),(item)=>{
item.onclick=(e)=>{
group_(document.getElementsByName('check'),(item)=>{
item.checked=false;
})
e.target.checked=true;

}
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="check" >
<input type="checkbox" name="check" >
<input type="checkbox" name="check" >
<input type="checkbox" name="check">
```

checkbox simple without loop

```js
var last;
document.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
if(e.target.getAttribute('name')=="myRadios"){
if(last)
last.checked=false;
}
e.target.checked=true;
last=e.target;
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="myRadios" value="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="myRadios" value="2" /> 2
```

Group By Single Div

```js
var group_=(el,callback)=>{
el.forEach((checkbox)=>{
callback(checkbox)
     })
}
var group_el=document.querySelectorAll("*[data-name] > input")
group_(group_el,(item)=>{
item.onclick=(e)=>{
group_(group_el,(item)=>{
item.checked=false;
})

e.target.checked=true;
}
})
```

```html
<div data-name="check">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

css single group div

```js
var last;
document.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
var closest=e.target.closest("*[data-name='check']");
console.log(closest)
if(e.target.closest("*[data-name]")){
if(last)
last.checked=false;
}

e.target.checked=true;
last=e.target;
})
```

```html
<div data-name="check">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2
</div>
```

check ,uncheck and single checked box

```js
var last;
document.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
var closest=e.target.closest("*[data-name='check']");
if(e.target.closest("*[data-name]")){
if(last)
last.checked=false;
}
if(e.target!==last)
last=e.target;
else
last=undefined;
})
```

```html
<div data-name="check">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

While JS is probably the way to go, it *could* be done with HTML and CSS only.

Here you have a fake radio button which is really a label for a real hidden radio button. By doing that, you get exactly the effect you need.

```
<style>
   #uncheck>input { display: none }
   input:checked + label { display: none }
   input:not(:checked) + label + label{ display: none } 
</style>

<div id='uncheck'>
  <input type="radio" name='food' id="box1" /> 
  Pizza 
    <label for='box1'>&#9678;</label> 
    <label for='box0'>&#9673;</label>
  <input type="radio" name='food' id="box2" /> 
  Ice cream 
    <label for='box2'>&#9678;</label> 
    <label for='box0'>&#9673;</label>
  <input type="radio" name='food' id="box0" checked />
</div>
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/tn70yxL8/2/

Now, that assumes you need non-selectable labels.

If you were willing to include the labels, you can technically avoid repeating the "uncheck" label by changing its text in CSS, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7tdb6quy/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
//Here is a solution using JQuery    
<input type = "checkbox" class="a"/>one
    <input type = "checkbox" class="a"/>two
    <input type = "checkbox" class="a"/>three
    <script>
       $('.a').on('change', function() {
            $('.a').not(this).prop('checked',false);
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

With plain old javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="groupname1" onClick="toggle(1,'groupname')"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="groupname2" onClick="toggle(2,'groupname')"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="groupname3" onClick="toggle(3,'groupname')" />

<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" id="diffGroupname1" onClick="toggle(1,'diffGroupname')"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" id="diffGroupname2" onClick="toggle(2,'diffGroupname')"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" id="diffGroupname3" onClick="toggle(3,'diffGroupname')" />
<script>
function toggle(which,group){
var counter=1;
var checkbox=document.getElementById(group+counter);
while(checkbox){
if(counter==which){

}else{
checkbox.checked=false;
}
counter++;
checkbox=document.getElementById(group+counter);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: also possible

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" class="groupname" onClick="toggle(this,'groupname')"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" class="groupname" onClick="toggle(this,'groupname')"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="group1[]" class="groupname" onClick="toggle(this,'groupname')" />

<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="diffGroupname" onClick="toggle(this,'diffGroupname')"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="diffGroupname" onClick="toggle(this,'diffGroupname')"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="diffGroupname" onClick="toggle(this,'diffGroupname')" />
<script>
function toggle(which,theClass){
var checkbox=document.getElementsByClassName(theClass);
for(var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++){
if(checkbox[i]==which){

}else{
checkbox[i].checked=false;
}
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Example With AngularJs**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('appc', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.selected = 'other';
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appc">
  <label>SELECTED: {{selected}}</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='male'" ng-true-value="'male'" ng-model="selected">Male
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='female'" ng-true-value="'female'" ng-model="selected">Female
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='other'" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-model="selected">Other
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('appc', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.selected = 'male';
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appc">
  <label>SELECTED: {{selected}}</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='male'" ng-true-value="'male'" ng-model="selected">Male
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='female'" ng-true-value="'female'" ng-model="selected">Female
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='other'" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-model="selected">Other
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone need a solution without an external javascript libraries you could use this example. A group of checkboxes allowing 0..1 values. You may click on the checkbox component or associated label text.

```
    <input id="mygroup1" name="mygroup" type="checkbox" value="1" onclick="toggleRadioCheckbox(this)" /> <label for="mygroup1">Yes</label>
    <input id="mygroup0" name="mygroup" type="checkbox" value="0" onclick="toggleRadioCheckbox(this)" /> <label for="mygroup0">No</label>

- - - - - - - - 

    function toggleRadioCheckbox(sender) {
        // RadioCheckbox: 0..1 enabled in a group 
        if (!sender.checked) return;
        var fields = document.getElementsByName(sender.name);
        for(var idx=0; idx<fields.length; idx++) {
            var field = fields[idx];
            if (field.checked && field!=sender)
                field.checked=false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necromancing: 
And **without** jQuery, for a checkbox structure like this:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_1" name="blubb_1" value="">--- Bitte ausw&#228;hlen ---
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_2" name="blubb_2" value="7">Testtracker
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_3" name="blubb_3" value="3">Kundenanfrage
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_4" name="blubb_4" value="2">Anpassung
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_5" name="blubb_5" value="1" checked="checked" >Fehler
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_6" name="blubb_6" value="4">Bedienung
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_7" name="blubb_7" value="5">Internes
</label>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="mytrackers_8" name="blubb_8" value="6">&#196;nderungswunsch
</label>
```

you would do it like this:

```
    /// attach an event handler, now or in the future, 
    /// for all elements which match childselector,
    /// within the child tree of the element maching parentSelector.
    function subscribeEvent(parentSelector, eventName, childSelector, eventCallback) {
        if (parentSelector == null)
            throw new ReferenceError("Parameter parentSelector is NULL");
        if (childSelector == null)
            throw new ReferenceError("Parameter childSelector is NULL");
        // nodeToObserve: the node that will be observed for mutations
        var nodeToObserve = parentSelector;
        if (typeof (parentSelector) === 'string')
            nodeToObserve = document.querySelector(parentSelector);
        var eligibleChildren = nodeToObserve.querySelectorAll(childSelector);
        for (var i = 0; i < eligibleChildren.length; ++i) {
            eligibleChildren[i].addEventListener(eventName, eventCallback, false);
        } // Next i 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712136/how-do-i-make-this-loop-all-children-recursively
        function allDescendants(node) {
            if (node == null)
                return;
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                var child = node.childNodes[i];
                allDescendants(child);
            } // Next i 
            // IE 11 Polyfill 
            if (!Element.prototype.matches)
                Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
            if (node.matches) {
                if (node.matches(childSelector)) {
                    // console.log("match");
                    node.addEventListener(eventName, eventCallback, false);
                } // End if ((<Element>node).matches(childSelector))
                // else console.log("no match");
            } // End if ((<Element>node).matches) 
            // else console.log("no matchfunction");
        } // End Function allDescendants 
        // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
        var callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
            for (var _i = 0, mutationsList_1 = mutationsList; _i < mutationsList_1.length; _i++) {
                var mutation = mutationsList_1[_i];
                // console.log("mutation.type", mutation.type);
                // console.log("mutation", mutation);
                if (mutation.type == 'childList') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; ++i) {
                        var thisNode = mutation.addedNodes[i];
                        allDescendants(thisNode);
                    } // Next i 
                } // End if (mutation.type == 'childList') 
                // else if (mutation.type == 'attributes') { console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
            } // Next mutation 
        }; // End Function callback 
        // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
        var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: true };
        // Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
        var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
        observer.observe(nodeToObserve, config);
    } // End Function subscribeEvent 


    function radioCheckbox_onClick() 
    { 
        // console.log("click", this);
        let box = this;
        if (box.checked) 
        {
            let name = box.getAttribute("name");
            let pos = name.lastIndexOf("_");
            if (pos !== -1) name = name.substr(0, pos);

            let group = 'input[type="checkbox"][name^="' + name + '"]';
            // console.log(group);
            let eles = document.querySelectorAll(group);
            // console.log(eles);
            for (let j = 0; j < eles.length; ++j) 
            {
                eles[j].checked = false;
            }
            box.checked = true;
        }
        else
            box.checked = false;
    }


    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group
    function radioCheckbox()
    { 
        // on instead of document...
        let elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')

        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
        {
            // console.log(elements[i]);
            elements[i].addEventListener("click", radioCheckbox_onClick, false);

        } // Next i 

    } // End Function radioCheckbox 


    function onDomReady()
    {
        console.log("dom ready");
        subscribeEvent(document, "click", 
            'input[type="checkbox"]', 
            radioCheckbox_onClick
        ); 

        // radioCheckbox();
    }

    if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDomReady, false);
    else if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", onDomReady);
    else window.onload = onDomReady;

    function onPageLoaded() {
        console.log("page loaded");
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("load", onPageLoaded, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", onPageLoaded);
    else window.onload = onPageLoaded;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Code snippet below demonstrates a simple approach for selecting only one checkbox in a group using JQuery .

---

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h3>Demonstration of Checkbox Toggle</h3>
    <p>
        <span><b>Letters:</b></span>
        A<input type="checkbox" name="A" >
        B<input type="checkbox" name="B" >
        C<input type="checkbox" name="C" >
        D<input type="checkbox" name="D" >
    </p>
    <p>
        <span><b>Numbers:</b></span>
        1<input type="checkbox" name="1" >
        2<input type="checkbox" name="2" >
        3<input type="checkbox" name="3" >
    </p>
     <p>
        <span><b>Birds:</b></span>
        Scarlet Ibis<input type="checkbox" name="Scarlet Ibis" >
        Cocrico <input type="checkbox" name="Cocrico" >
        hummingbird <input type="checkbox" name="hummingbird" >
    </p>
</body>

<script>
    $(function()
    {
        function toggle(choices,name) 
        {
            if(choices.includes(name))
            {
                for( i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
                {
                if(name !=choices[i])
                    $('input[name="' + choices[i] + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false); 
                }
            }
        }
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() 
        {
            var letters = ["A","B","C","D"];
            var numbers = ["1", "2", "3"];
            var birds = ["Scarlet Ibis", "Cocrico", "hummingbird"];
            
            toggle(letters,this.name);
            toggle(numbers,this.name);
            toggle(birds,this.name);
        });

    });
</script>
</html>
```