# Since radio buttons cannot be unchecked, what is the purpose of them?

Tags: html

Aren't check (tick) buttons more useful?

Why do they exist?

They seem quite unnecessary to me, can you please explain to me the purpose of radio buttons?

Comment: Also check out:  http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If there was a question that asked for your gender, it would be bad design to use check-boxes - what if someone checked both? Or how about "early" and "late" - you can't be both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used so that only one option can be chosen out of a group of options. Check buttons allow the user to choose multiple options.

### Edit:

If the goal is to have check boxes for which only 0 or 1 of the boxes in a group is checked, then check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/zGEaa/) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709425/612266). It presents a simple way to do this using jQuery.

Here's the Javascript code used:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === true) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this also possible with check(tick) buttons too?

Comment: Is what also possible? Only choosing one option?

Comment: Yes is only choosing one option possible with check buttons

Comment: It might be confusing for the user because most users are used to being able to select multiple check boxes, but [here is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group) with an answer that allows you to do that using jQuery.

Comment: Danke schon. C'est tres interessant.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are for multiple selection while radio buttons only allow a single selection. It is really by design of HTML and before that standard user interfaces that checkboxes and radio buttons behave this way.

Radio buttons derive their name from the design of the station presets on a radio (think car dash radio). Back before radios were all digital, those radio buttons physically pushed in causing the single selection to push the existing selection out.