# HTML checkbox - allow to check only one checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox

I have some checkboxes in each row in my table. Each one checkbox has `name='myName'` because I want to select only one checkbox in each row. But something I'm missing because I'm able to check all of them:

[image]

but I want that result:

[image]

what am I missing here ?

Comment: It's not how checkboxes work, if you want to make them work like this you should use javascript to handle that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The unique name identifier applies to radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" />
```

change your checkboxes to radio and everything should be working

Comment: and alsob that code can be used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group/9709425#9709425

Comment: Unique name you can identify to Checkbox also..
Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39405214/2545270

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes, by design, are meant to be toggled on or off.   They are not dependent on other checkboxes, so you can turn as many on and off as you wish.

Radio buttons, however, are designed to only allow one element of a group to be selected at any time.

References:

Checkboxes:  [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/checkbox)

Radio Buttons:  [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/radio)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
     $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
         var chks = document.getElementById('<%= chkRoleInTransaction.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
         for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            chks[i].checked = false;
         }
         if (chks.length > 1)
            $(this)[0].checked = true;
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sapSet = mbo.getThisMboSet()
sapCount = sapSet.count()
saplist = []

if sapCount > 1:
   for i in range(sapCount):`enter code here`
     defaultCheck = sapSet.getMbo(i)
     saplist.append(defaultCheck.getInt("HNADEFACC"))
   defCount = saplist.count(1)
   if defCount > 1:
      errorgroup = " Please Note: you are allowed"
      errorkey = "  only One Default Account"
   if defCount < 1:
      errorgroup = " Please enter "
      errorkey = "  at leat One Default Account"
else:
   mbo.setValue("HNADEFACC",1,MboConstants.NOACCESSCHECK)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#OvernightOnshore').click(function () {
    if ($('#OvernightOnshore').prop("checked") == true) {
        if ($('#OvernightOffshore').prop("checked") == true) {
            $('#OvernightOffshore').attr('checked', false)
        }
    }
})

$('#OvernightOffshore').click(function () {
    if ($('#OvernightOffshore').prop("checked") == true) {
        if ($('#OvernightOnshore').prop("checked") == true) {
            $('#OvernightOnshore').attr('checked', false);
        }
    }
})
```

This above code snippet will allow you to use checkboxes over radio buttons, but have the same functionality of radio buttons where you can only have one selected.