# Disable onclick when event is from another onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 checkboxes. They shall be synced, so i did some jQuery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="jQuery('#check2').trigger('click')">
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="jQuery('#check1').trigger('click')">
```

When I press check1, check2 will be checked/unchecked, but also triggers the onclick of check2, so check1 will be checked -> unchecked. How can I solv this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Comment: Is this just for testing? It seems very odd behaviour to require, possibly even an XY problem.

Comment: Set checked property instead of triggering click event

Comment: Is it getting in to an infinite loop?! As in the check boxes keep getting checked and unchecked for forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing elements inside parent container , using `change` event attached to `parentElement :checkbox` ; within `change` handler set siblings elements `checked` property to current element `checked` property

```js
$("div :checkbox").on("sync", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id)
})

$("div :checkbox").on("change", function() {
  $(this).siblings().prop("checked", this.checked)
  .trigger("sync")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thx dude - that's what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should use a radio button for this, as it has the desired functionality built in. To answer your question however, you need to set/remove the checked state of the box, instead of triggering the click.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" onclick="jQuery('#check2').attr('checked', false)">
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" onclick="jQuery('#check1').attr('checked', false)">
```

If you want to sync them, then you could move the JS so that it is not inline and use something like:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var boxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    boxes.on('click', function(evt) {
        var other = boxes.not( $(this) );

        if( other.is(':checked') )
            other.removeAttr('checked');
        else
            other.attr('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Comment: On jq 1.6+ you should use prop()

Comment: You could always simple use `.removeAttr('checked');`

Comment: But this doesn't toggle it. If it was *un*-checked, then this wouldn't set the other to true.

Comment: and @A.Wolff what's the difference between `prop()` and `attr()`?

Comment: "They shall be **synced**" As there is no different default state set, both checkboxes shall always have the same state - at least my interpretation of the scripts used in the question

Comment: [`.prop()` vs. `.attr()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event you're using in your html elements is unnecessary and confusing.  Instead, I would suggest you add a class to both elements, and then you can uncheck all elements other than the one that was just clicked on.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" class="myClass" >Box 1
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" class="myClass">Box 2
```

**JQuery / Javascript**

```
var $checkboxes = $('.myClass');
$checkboxes.click(function() {
   $checkboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tjk25kc8/1/)