# Dynamic created checkbox validation is not working properly in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to validate the dynamically created checkbox,for each question some checkbox answer, user select at least one...only first checkbox answer is worked for all the questions if select second checkbox it shows not checked.user can select any option.

```js
$(function() {
  //function validate_form() {
  $("#continueButton").click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
      //var rname = $(this).attr('name');
      var rname = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(rname);
      var check_box = $('#' + rname),
        names1 = $.unique(check_box.map(function() {
          return this.name;
        })),
        checked = check_box.filter(function() {
          return this.checked;
        });
      alert(names1.length);
      alert(checked.length);
      //alert(check_box.is(':checked'));
      //alert(check_box.is(':checked'));
      if (names1.length != checked.length) {
        //alert('all answers are checked');
        isCheck = false;
        alert("select checkbox");
        //$('#e_'+rname).html("Please select the answer");
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (isCheck) {
      //return true;
      flagchk = 1
    } else {
      flagchk = 0;
      return false;
    }
    if (flagchk == 1) {
      //if(flagradio == 1 && flagchk==1){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="sample" id="sample" method="post" action="sample.php">
  <label for="How was the breakfast?" id="label_error">How was the breakfast?</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="20" name="20_85" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="85" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Not good
  <input type="checkbox" id="20" name="20_84" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="84" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Good
  <span class="red_12">*</span>
  <br>
  <label for="How was the meal ?" id="label_error">How was the meal ?</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_92" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="92" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Good
  <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_93" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="93" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Average
  <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_94" style="width: auto;display:    inline-block;height: auto;" value="94" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Not good
  <div class="two-col buttonContainer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="continueButton" class="button">Book It Now</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can user select all the options for a question ?

Comment: thanks @ Rayon Dabre...if i select notgood it is shows check as 1.

Comment: yes uesr can select all the options also

Comment: `Not good` and `Good` too ?

Comment: check the validation,if select first option ok,if select second option it is not validating...it show please check the answer..

Comment: You should use radio buttons I suppose...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105754/discussion-between-fakkir-mohamed-sait-and-rayon-dabre).

Comment: Use radio button instead of check box..                                                        OR if u are using check box check th link                                                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Answer (score 0):

> Use a parent `div` to for am group of the question so that manipulations will be easier.

`$(':checkbox')` selector will return all the elements having type as `checkbox`

`.filter` can be used to filter out element based on the condition.

Try this:

```js
$("#continueButton").click(function() {
  $('.form-elem').each(function() {
    var length = $(this).find(':checkbox').filter(function() {
      return this.checked;
    }).length;
    if (length == 0) {
      alert($(this).find('label').text() + ' :: not answered!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="sample" id="sample" method="post" action="sample.php">
  <div class="form-elem">
    <label for="How was the breakfast?" id="label_error">How was the breakfast?</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="20" name="20_85" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="85" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Not good
    <input type="checkbox" id="20" name="20_84" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="84" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Good
    <span class="red_12">*</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-elem">
    <label for="How was the meal ?" id="label_error">How was the meal ?</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_92" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="92" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Good
    <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_93" style="width: auto;display: inline-block;height: auto;" value="93" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Average
    <input type="checkbox" id="28" name="28_94" style="width: auto;display:    inline-block;height: auto;" value="94" class="checkbox_check">&nbsp;Not good
  </div>
  <div class="two-col buttonContainer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="continueButton" class="button">Book It Now</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/eynLbLyn/)