# How to limit the amount of checked boxes to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So I have a few lists of checkboxes, all with the a slightly different class of single-check with a number on the end indicating which list they're in, since I'm not using radio buttons. How would I go about making it so that any checkbox that is in the same class can't be checked if another checkbox in that class is already checked?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons? That's what they're for...

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using radio buttons for this?

Comment: Possible double answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Comment: is simply unchecking all others with the same class an option? Or does the first checked box have to block the others?

Comment: USe radio button and style them to look like checkbox. The only reason for radio button's existence is to help you select single option. Please don't take it away from them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `jQuery.not` when a checkbox is clicked, you could set the `checked` property on all the other checkboxes in that group, to `false` (meaning they won't be checked).

```
$(function() {
    $(".myCheckboxInGroup1").on("click", function() {
        $(".myCheckboxInGroup1").not(this).prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/Gigabyte-Giant/pen/wWavZj

Comment: If there's not a common class, use the selector `input[type="checkbox"][name="whatever"]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function howtoreadresults(){
   var r = [];
   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(i,o){
      r.push($(o).attr('group')+'='+$(o).val());
   });
   return r;
}

$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e){
   $('[group='+$(this).attr('group')+']:checked').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);
   console.log(howtoreadresults());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' group='cars' value='red' />
<input type='checkbox' group='cars' value='blue' />
<input type='checkbox' group='cars' value='green' />
<input type='checkbox' group='bike' value='red' />
<input type='checkbox' group='bike' value='blue' />
<input type='checkbox' group='bike' value='green' />
```

Comment: also, i suggest you to change your title to "how to replace radio buttons by checkboxes ?"