# Chrome and IE doesn't fire change event on time when we click on label assigned for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

On a specific condition when user checks a checkbox, I want to show an alert message and uncheck the checkbox, so to uncheck a checkbox I am calling click function on it so that it internally unchecks and also fire necessary events.

I have a checkbox and label which is for checkbox, with `for` property properly set for the label

- In firefox, unchecking works on checkbox and it's label.
- In chrome,  unchecking works on checkbox for but not on label.
- In chrome,  unchecking doesn't work on checkbox or label.

With specific timeout I was able to solve this problem, but I want a solution without using timeout.

You can see code below and also access [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3o871nr/2/) here.

```js
$("#id1").on("change", function(event) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    $(event.target).trigger("click");
  }
});

$("#id2").on("change", function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      $(event.target).trigger("click");
    }
  }, 5);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="id1">
<label for="id1">Click me</label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="" id="id2">
<label for="id2">Works with timeout</label>
```

```
This work quite well with Firefox but not in chrome and IE9, IE10
```

> I am looking for javascript or jQuery solution

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @epascarello : I have a boxes and inside it I am having checkbox, I am allowing user to select only one type of boxes so if user tries to select other types of boxes then I show alert message and uncheck it, ... Why I want to fire click event is because, I am also highlight-de-highlight box when checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#id1").change(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    this.checked = false;
  }
});
```

i've tried in chrome and it seems to work, basically instead of click the checkbox it modifies it's state

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL5bxepp/1/)

updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yL5bxepp/3/) triggering click event

Comment: but it isn't going to fire a click event on checkbox to uncheck it, so my other changes that depends on javascript uncheck event, breaks

Comment: i've added an updated jsfiddle triggering click event

Comment: it fires a click event, https://jsfiddle.net/yL5bxepp/6/, if you look for a click event attaching a listener to a change event maybe the problem is elsewhere... 'change' and 'click' are different events. in the first comment you said you need a click event, then you said you need a change event, which one do you need?

Comment: I need change event

Comment: but then change event will be fired two times in FF right? basically I want to avoid browser specific code

Comment: So your basic idea is to set checkbox state differently and firing event differently, right?

Comment: your question is unclear, maybe i understood what you need, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group

Comment: no, not like that... there are many checkbox with two different types, so at a time I can select only one type of checkboxes...

Comment: what do you mean with "type of checkbox"? maybe you are using checkboxes likes radio buttons? however i've answered your question, you are just asking other things in comments, i won't reply again

Comment: Nevermind, @lorenzo I am able to pickup from your answer and my issue is solved, thanks a lot for your help and time