# only checkbox to be checked at a time

Tags: javascript

Guys I have 2 checkbox and when one checkbox is checked the other has to be disabled and again if unchecked both checkbox has to be enabled (only onecheck box can be clicked at a time). I cannot use a radio button and checkboxes name/id cannot be similar. I will greatly appreciate if you guys can help. pure javascript. thx

```js
function change(type){
    var checked = document.getElementById(type.id);
    var wan=document.getElementsByName('test');
    var ven = document.getElementsByName('testing');
    
         
    
    if (checked.checked) {
     if(wan){
     document.getElementById('testing').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('test').disabled =false;

     }
     if(ven){
  document.getElementById('testing').value = 2;
  document.getElementById('test').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('testing').disabled =false;

     }
     }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" onclick="change(this)"/>test
<input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="testing" onclick="change(this)"/>testing
```

Comment: *I cannot use a radio button and checkboxes name/id cannot be similar.* So, you can't use HTML the right way? What kind of requirement is that?

Comment: I know, i wish I could use the radio button.

Comment: Why can't you use radio buttons?

Comment: If one checkbox is checked then the unchecked checkbox is disabled? If it's disabled how is it to be checked? Is this a way to ensure user has no way of changing his/her choice once it's made? Or does the checked checkbox need to be unchecked so that both are enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function change(){
    var wan = document.getElementById('test');
    var ven = document.getElementById('testing');
    
         
    
    if (wan.checked) {
     document.getElementById('testing').disabled= true;
     document.getElementById('test').disabled= false;

    }else if (ven.checked){
  document.getElementById('testing').value = 2;
  document.getElementById('test').disabled =true;
     document.getElementById('testing').disabled =false;
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('testing').disabled= false;
  document.getElementById('test').disabled =false;
 }
 }
</script>

<body>
 
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test" onClick="change()"/>test
<input type="checkbox" id="testing" name="testing" onClick="change()"/>testing
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: man you are a life saver, thank you very much. I tried to upvote this answer but i dont have enough reputation. ur is the right answer. thank u very much and god bless u

Answer (score 0):

See comments inline below:

```js
// Get both checkboxes into an Array
let boxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.chk"));

// Loop over the boxes
boxes.forEach(function(box){    

  // Set up event handler
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){

    // If the currently clicked box is checked
    if(box.checked){
      // Loop over the boxes again
      boxes.forEach(function(cb){
        // Disable the box if it's not the current box
        if(cb !== box){
          cb.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
      });    
    } else {
      // Loop over boxes again
      boxes.forEach(function(b){
        b.removeAttribute("disabled");  // Enable the box
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="test">test
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" name="testing">testing
```

Answer (score 0):

you should radio button for this it would be better anyway if it can help

```
Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2"  onclick="myFunction2()">
Checkbox1: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1"  onclick="myFunction1()">

<script>
function myFunction2() {
    var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");    
    var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
     if (checkBox2.checked == true){
        checkBox1.checked = false
    } 
}
function myFunction1() {
    var checkBox1 = document.getElementById("myCheck1");    
    var checkBox2 = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
    if (checkBox1.checked == true){
        checkBox2.checked = false
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use either a common class or some dataset element. You can just just ask the browser to give you all of them using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You can then use any [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

```js
function checkOneOfGroup(selector, checkedId) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
    element.checked = element.id === checkedId;
  });
}

const selector = "input[type=checkbox].group1"; 

function handleChange(element) {
  checkOneOfGroup(selector, element.target.id);
}

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
});

checkOneOfGroup(selector, 'apple'); // start with apple checked
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="orange"><label for="orange">orange</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="apple"><label for="apple">apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="banana"><label for="banana">banana</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="pear"><label for="pear">pear</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" id="peach"><label for="peach">peach</label>
```

using a [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) element instead

```js
function checkOneOfGroup(selector, checkedId) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
    element.checked = element.id === checkedId;
  });
}

const selector = "input[type=checkbox][data-foo=group1]"; 

function handleChange(element) {
  checkOneOfGroup(selector, element.target.id);
}

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
});

checkOneOfGroup(selector, 'apple'); // start with apple checked
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-foo="group1" id="orange"><label for="orange">orange</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-foo="group1" id="apple"><label for="apple">apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-foo="group1" id="banana"><label for="banana">banana</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-foo="group1" id="pear"><label for="pear">pear</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-foo="group1" id="peach"><label for="peach">peach</label>
```

You could also just surround them in some other element and use that as a selctor

```js
function checkOneOfGroup(selector, checkedId) {
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
    element.checked = element.id === checkedId;
  });
}

const selector = "#fruits input[type=checkbox]"; 

function handleChange(element) {
  checkOneOfGroup(selector, element.target.id);
}

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
});

checkOneOfGroup(selector, 'apple'); // start with apple checked
```

```html
<div id="fruits">
 <input type="checkbox" id="orange"><label for="orange">orange</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="apple"><label for="apple">apple</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="banana"><label for="banana">banana</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="pear"><label for="pear">pear</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="peach"><label for="peach">peach</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

The HFCC API allows us to access `<form>s` and all of their form controls with a terse and simple syntax:

> Collect all `<form>s` in a page: **`var FORM = document.forms`**
> Collect all **form controls** of a `<form>`: **`var FC = FORM.elements`**
> Reference a form control by `#id` or `[name]`: **`var CHK = FC.nameOfInput`**

---

### Demo

```js
var sw = document.forms[0];
var ui = sw.elements;
var yin = ui.yin;
var yng = ui.yang;

sw.onchange = flip;

function flip(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id === 'yin' && tgt.checked) {
    tgt.disabled = false;
    yng.disabled = true;
  } else if (tgt.id === 'yang' && tgt.checked) {
    tgt.disabled = false;
    yin.disabled = true;
  } else if (!tgt.checked) {
    yin.disabled = false;
    yng.disabled = false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 "Ceviche One";
}

body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background: #900;
}

form {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 2rem
}

[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

[name=yin]+label {
  border: 3px double #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

[name=yang]+label {
  border: 3px double #000;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

input[type=checkbox]:disabled+label {
  border-color: #aaa;
  color: #aaa;
  background: #666;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  border: 3px double #980;
  color: #f00;
  background: none;
}

.symbol {
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: fit-content;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 30%;
  vertical-align: sub;
  padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ceviche+One" rel="stylesheet">

<form id='switch'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yin" name="yin" value='0' />
  <label for='yin'>Yin</label>
  <label class='symbol'>&#9775;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="yang" name="yang" value='1' />
  <label for='yang'>Yang</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

A similar question has already been asked, here [html select only one checkbox in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group)

By the way, using radio buttons would be better in my opinion, since it already does what you want to do.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not using jquery

Comment: If you scroll down there'll be some solutions in pure Javascript as you want.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.