# Add class to parent div when radio button is selected in Angular 8

Tags: angular, data-binding

Not long started with Angular.

So I need to add a class to a parent div when a radio button is selected in Angular. I have been led to believe that this can be possible using [ngClass] and maybe even with [ngSelected] but haven't had any luck with it in the last few days.

What I think I am looking for is a class to be added to a div when a radio button is selected, I have seen static examples of this but nothing dynamic.

```
<div id="one">
<id="two">
<input type="radio" /><label>Text 1</label>
</div>
</div>
```

when the radio button is selected, the class will be added to the div 
 with the id="one". It seems to be quite a simple thing but I am having no love with this at all.

Thanks!

Comment: your code is missing a div <HERE id="two>

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make `id=one` to `class=one`(make `one` a class). Then use `[clas.classname]="condition"`

```
<div class="one" [class.myClass]="isChecked">
  <div id="two">
     <input id="radio" type="radio" (change)="checked($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally in `.ts` file, `isChecked = checkbox.checked;`

See this [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy7hvu?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: That's awesome Harunur! Out of interest, if I wanted to have multiple radio buttons, and only change the background to that radio button that has been checked, how would I go about this?

Comment: Then you have to keep track of which radio button is checked using id attribute.
See this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294631/how-can-i-bind-event-of-one-or-more-arithmatic-operation-to-checkbox/53294782#53294782`

Comment: I am sure this works but I am being asked to complete this task in an Angular fashion. Appreciate the link though!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<div [className]="condition ? 'example-class' : 'other-class'"></div>
```

Please refer to this link for more details:
[Class Binding in Angular](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngclass/)

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can Do like that :

```
addClass = false;

radioChanage(event) {
 this.addClass = true;
 }
```

in the template.

```
<div id="one" [ngClass]="{'className' : addClass}">
<id="two">
<input type="radio" (change)="radioChanage($event)" /><label>Text 1</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="one" [class.newClass]="radioBtn">
    <div id="two" >
        <input type="radio" [ngModel]="radioBtn" /><label>Text 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
selected: string = '';
```

In your html

```
<div id="one" [ngClass]="{'myClass': selected == 'one'}">
    <div id="two">
        <input type="radio" value="one" [(ngModel)]="selected" /><label>Text 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regards