# If I have two check boxes how do I make it so that if one is checked the other is unchecked?

Tags: html, ionic3

I'm working on an app and one of the pages requires the user to choose payment by credit/card or cash. I want to make it so that both check boxes cannot be checked at the same time (If one is checked the other is unchecked).

I have tried making an event with ionChange so that if one of them is checked the boolean value of the other checkboxes becomes false.

HTML

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Credit/Debit Card (N/A)</ion-label>   
    <ion-checkbox item-start [(ngModel)]='CC' (ionChange)="checked()"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  <br/><br/>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Cash</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-start [(ngModel)]='Cash' (ionChange)="checked()"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
```

Typescript

```
 Cash = false;    
  CC = false;      

  checked(){
    if(this.Cash == true){
      this.CC = false;
    }

    if(this.CC == true){
      this.Cash = false
    }
  }
```

I expected this to work but it is still possible to check both boxes.

Comment: using the radio instead of a checkbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html select only one checkbox in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this is to use Radio-button instead of Checkbox .but if you want to
do it by checkbox than the code is at follow:-

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="1" [(ngModel)]="check1"
 (change)="onchange($event)"/>
 {{check1}}


 <input type="checkbox" name="2" [(ngModel)]="check2"
  (change)="onchange1($event)"/>
 {{check2}}
```

TypeScript

```
export class AppComponent {

  check1: boolean;
  check2: boolean;

  onchange(event: any) {
    if (this.check1 == !event.target.checked) {
      this.check2 = true;
    }
    else {
      this.check2 = false;
    }
  }

  onchange1(event: any) {
    if (this.check2 == !event.target.checked) {
      this.check1 = true;
    }
    else {
      this.check1 = false;
    }
  }
}
```

hope its work fine for you.

Comment: This is a very specific answer which will only work for two checkboxes, using a group is better approach.Check out the link I had shared above