# How to link checkboxInputs without using radioButtons in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create two `checkboxInput`s in an R Shiny app which behave in a way that only one can be enabled at a time but having neither enabled should also be an option (essentially they both can't be true at the same time).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("box1", "Test1", value = F),
  checkboxInput("box2", "Test2", value = F)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$box1, {

    if (input$box2){
      updateCheckboxInput(session,
                          "box2",
                          value = F)
    }

  })

  observeEvent(input$box2, {

    if (input$box1){
      updateCheckboxInput(session,
                          "box1",
                          value = F)
    }

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The above app almost does what I want but selecting `box2` when `box1` is selected just disables both of them instead of selecting `box2` and unselecting `box1`. Ideally, when one of the boxes are selected, selecting the other one should disable the former and enable the latter. Is this possible without using radioButtons?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sourcing the javascript code from [html select only one checkbox in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group)

So if you save `checkboxOne.js` under `www` directory:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
    // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
    // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});

});



ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "checkboxOne.js"
    )),

  checkboxGroupInput("check_box", "Test", choices = c("Test1", "Test2"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```