# Check only one checkbox in each row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I want to be able to check only one checkbox out of 4 checkboxes using Jquery Javascript, I have multiple forms with 4 checkboxes in the same page generated by PHP,
My approach is

```js
<script>
        $('input.chk1').on('change', function() {
            $('input.chk1').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
        $('input.chk2').on('change', function() {
            $('input.chk2').not(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="chk1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="chk1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="chk1"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" class="chk1"/>
</form>


<form action="">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" class="chk2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" class="chk2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" class="chk2"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk4" class="chk2"/>
</form>

......
```

What is the best way to achieve this since I have so many forms each in a list of items?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id like `chk1`

Comment: why you not use radio button instead of checboxes if you want to check just one checkbox in single form?

Comment: Why radio will not work? Its only what you need, since you want select only one from multiple.

Comment: yes, exactly, realized my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to use radio button instead of checkboxes

Also this solution fixed my problem:
[html select only one checkbox in a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group/9709425#9709425)