# Yup - validating only 1 checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, validation, yup

I have a form with 2 checkboxes - the constraint is that a max of 1 of the checkboxes can be checked. In other words, both checkboxes can't be checked.

I have added logic to the form to disable the other checkbox when 1 is checked. But I'd also like to validate this.

My attempt was this:

```
yup.object().shape({
  textInput: yup.string().trim().required('Text input is required.'),
  checkbox1: yup.boolean()
    .when('checkbox2', {
      is: true,
      then: yup.boolean().isFalse()
    }),
  checkbox2: yup.boolean()
    .when('checkbox1', {
      is: true,
      then: yup.boolean().isFalse()
    }),
}, [[ 'checkbox1', 'checkbox2' ]])
```

But this causes strange behavior - it seems to return a false validation when the first is checked, and then the second is checked. But doesn't return a false validation if the second is checked, and then the first is checked.

Is it possible to do a validation like this?

Answer (score -1):

I would instead of using checkboxes use the input type="radio". This only allows one of the choices to be selected. Here is some example documentation from w3schools.com.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: The problem is I need to allow none to be checked too.

Comment: You can reset them using a reset button. [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_reset.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_reset.asp)

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. The 2 checkboxes are distinct items (and I could add a 3rd checkbox, independent of the other 2) - radio buttons aren't really suitable here. There is logic in the form to disable checkbox1 when checkbox2 is selected, and vice versa. But I'm trying to validate that only 1 is selected, using `yup` - that is the question here.

Comment: Ok, sorry this didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in another answer you can use radio input types as it is the ideal option.

But if you want only checkboxes then go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group). It has many interesting approaches.